# Bluehost server error 500

Tags: .htaccess, shared-hosting

So I created a simple mvc project and uploaded In bluehost, but I'm having an server error problem which I guess is because the `.htaccess` in my project. I've done some research if `mod_rewrite` is enabled in bluehost, and found that by default it is enabled. But I still get the server error. I hope someone can help me out thanks.

Here my `.htaccess` inside my public folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /streaming/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here is the error I get:

[server error 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Lsf.png)

Comment: HTTP 500 means there was an error processing the HTTP request. The problem is almost certainly with your PHP code, and not with bluehost or .htaccess.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll try to check the index.php to see if there are any errors thanks.

Comment: Are you able to look at what the PHP error log says?

Comment: yep here the error
[06-Jan-2016 05:46:25 America/Denver] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home2/bsittwoz/public_html/prtvcitizenpatroller/index.php on line 94

Comment: I guess this line RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] here is not working.

Comment: What is on line 94 of your index.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error would indicate that you are trying to perform an operation or function on an array when it is expecting a string. For example, if you have something like:

```
echo $_GET;
```

This will not work, because $_GET is an array and the echo command only works with strings and other primitive data types.

Instead, you should either specify the index that you want such as:

```
echo $_GET['url'];
```

or if you want all the data in the array you can either loop through each element of the array and process each string one at a time such as:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
   echo "<p>The value of $key is $value</p>";
}
```

or use a different method that does support the entire array such as:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Of course this is all guesswork without knowing what your code on line 94 actually says.

Comment: I know about this but thanks anyway. But my problem now is on htaccess because this line "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]" doesn't seem to work. I don't know if bluehost enables this line "Allow Override" line by default.

Comment: Based on the error you are receiving I am quite sure the problem is in your index.php and not in your .htaccess.

Comment: Yes I understand what the errors mean. but a this line here is not working the way it should be "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]", and this is my code in my index line 94 "$_GET['url'];"

Comment: @WilloPillow Can you paste at least lines 90 to 95 of your code so that I can get an idea of what is going on? It makes no sense that `$_GET['url']` is your entire line 94. You can modify your question above with those lines and respond to me here that you have modified it.